# How to check if the user has entered a single letter?

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading a character and want to check if that is single character and is a letter. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -p "Enter something: " char
if [[ ${#char} != 1 && "$char" != *[a-z]* ]]; then
    echo "Not a valid input"
else
    echo "Its a valid input"
fi
```

The o/p is below:

```
[root@host-7 ~]# sh -x t
+ read -p 'Enter something: ' char
Enter something: 1
+ [[ 1 != 1 ]]
+ echo 'Its a valid input'
Its a valid input
```

While executing the script only first condition is getting executed and its not checking the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not evaluating 2nd condition because first condition is failing as you're entering only 1 character in input and there is `&&` between 2 conditions.

If you enter 2 character input like `ab` then you'll see both conditions getting evaluated.

---

You can use `-n1` to restrict input to one character only like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -n1 -p "Enter something: " char
echo
if [[ "$char" != *[a-z]* ]];then
   echo "Not a valid input"
else
   echo "Its a valid input"
fi
```

And run it as:

```
bash -x ./t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to test for a single letter, you can use the POSIX character class `[[:alpha:]]` or equivalently `[a-zA-Z]`.  No need to check the length or use wildcards as a single bash pattern will only test multiple occurrences of a match when using `extglob` optional [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

```
read -p "Enter something: " char
if [[ $char != [[:alpha:]] ]]; then
    echo "Not a valid input"
else
    echo "It's a valid input"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `if` statement to:

```
if [[ $char != [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
```

It will check if `$char` is a single character and is a letter (a-z,A-Z).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter something: " char
if [[ $char != [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
    echo "Not a valid input"
else
    echo "Its a valid input"
fi
```

Output will be like this:

```
ab : inavlid
a  : valid
1  : invalid
12 : invalid
A  : valid
AB : invalid
```

Comment: With default settings, `[a-z]` will only match lower case.